# hide textfields instantly when check a radio button

Tags: javascript, radio-button, show-hide

What I want is when the user chooses the first option the textfield will disappear and when the users chooses the second the textfield will appear again instantly. Here's some code:

```
<input type="radio" name="RadioGroup0" value="1" id="student"  />
<input type="radio" name="RadioGroup0" value="0" id="not student"  />
```

and want to hide/show this:

```
<label for="department">department:</label>
<input name="department" type="text" class="label" value=""  />
```

I have tried anything so I'll appreciate any answer

Comment: what is the `anything` that you have tried?

Comment: if you googled it you would find the answer so I think you didn't tried `anything`!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: creating a function onclick/onchange which shows me an alert when check an option. it worked with the first selection only, when i change my selection nothing happened. in this function i tried to change style.visibility and do hide() but nothing worked for me. i don't know how to use jqueries and i didn't success with my try. which is ur opinion?

Answer (score 0):

On the *click*, *keyup*, and *change* events, show or hide the appropriate elements (jQuery makes this easier). The reason for handling all the events is that the value change may only be triggered after the element loses focus.

Happy coding.